# Beanstalk Re-use environnent variable into an other environnent variable

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

In the beanstalk configuration, i need to re-use an environement variable to an other environmeent variable. How can i do this here an exemple :

```
AWS_SECRET:A
AWS_KEY:B
AWS_REGION:C
AWS_ID:D

MESSENGER_DNS: https://sqs.${AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${AWS_ID}/?access_key=${AWS_KEY}&secret_key=${AWS_SECRET}
```